# create filter in functions.php

Tags: functions, themes, filters

I want to create a filter in my functions.php theme to change the URL of $icon_html in this plugin function.

```
public function get_icon() {
// paypal icon
$icon_html = '<img src="paypal.png" />';

return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_gateway_icon', $icon_html, $this->get_id() );
}
```

How to perform this? $icon_html is not unique.

Thank you, Thibault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you see `apply_filters( 'filter_name', $value )`, you can use `add_filter()` to replace or modify the value of `$value`:

```
add_filter( 'filter_name', 'callback_function' );
```

Where `callback_function` is a function that you create. That function will accept `$value` as an argument, and needs to return a new value. So for your example, that will look like this:

```
function wpse_275788_replace_icon( $icon_html, $id ) {
    $icon_html = 'Put new icon html here.';

    return $icon_html;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_gateway_icon', 'wpse_275788_replace_icon', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thank you but the problem with this, it will replace all values with the same $icon_html - And my plugin use different $icon_html values depending on where it is located.

Comment: You would just need to add `if` statements to the function to set `$icon_html` to different values based on your conditions. What do you mean "where it's located"? No one will be able to help unless you specify.

Comment: With your code this how it goes: https://snag.gy/HWCvf2.jpg

Comment: I updated my answer to accept the gateway id. Copy my code exactly, but replace `'Put new icon html here.'` with `$id`, and tell me what appears.

Comment: Same. Both icons are replaced.

Comment: But with what, it should be the id of the gateway. If I know the id of the gateway I can update my code to do what you want.

Comment: How can I know the ID myself?

Comment: If you made the change I suggested the icons should have been replaced with the id.

Comment: Not really, the picture is still updated like this: https://snag.gy/HWCvf2.jpg

Comment: Wow sorry I haven't read carefuly. This way I could see the ID, and I did the condition like this:
if ($id == 'braintree_paypal') {  
It works! THANKS

Answer (score 0):

I want to update the paypal icon:

[image]

Here how they put the credit card icons:

```
/**
     * Returns the gateway icon markup
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @see WC_Payment_Gateway::get_icon()
     * @return string icon markup
     */
    public function get_icon() {

        $icon = '';

        // specific icon
        if ( $this->icon ) {

            // use icon provided by filter
            $icon = sprintf( '<img src="%s" alt="%s" class="sv-wc-payment-gateway-icon wc-%s-payment-gateway-icon" />', esc_url( \WC_HTTPS::force_https_url( $this->icon ) ), esc_attr( $this->get_title() ), esc_attr( $this->get_id_dasherized() ) );
        }

        // credit card images
        if ( ! $icon && $this->supports_card_types() && $this->get_card_types() ) {

            // display icons for the selected card types
            foreach ( $this->get_card_types() as $card_type ) {

                $card_type = SV_WC_Payment_Gateway_Helper::normalize_card_type( $card_type );

                if ( $url = $this->get_payment_method_image_url( $card_type ) ) {
                    $icon .= sprintf( '<img src="%s" alt="%s" class="sv-wc-payment-gateway-icon wc-%s-payment-gateway-icon" width="40" height="25" style="width: 40px; height: 25px;" />', esc_url( $url ), esc_attr( $card_type ), esc_attr( $this->get_id_dasherized() ) );
                }
            }
        }

        // echeck image
        if ( ! $icon && $this->is_echeck_gateway() ) {

            if ( $url = $this->get_payment_method_image_url( 'echeck' ) ) {
                $icon .= sprintf( '<img src="%s" alt="%s" class="sv-wc-payment-gateway-icon wc-%s-payment-gateway-icon" width="40" height="25" style="width: 40px; height: 25px;" />', esc_url( $url ), esc_attr( 'echeck' ), esc_attr( $this->get_id_dasherized() ) );
            }
        }

        /* This filter is documented in WC core */
        return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_gateway_icon', $icon, $this->get_id() );
    }
```

and here how they put the Paypal icon:

```
public function get_icon() {

        // from https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/logos-buttons
        $icon_html = '<img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/i/buttons/PP_logo_h_100x26.png" alt="PayPal" />';

        return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_gateway_icon', $icon_html, $this->get_id() );
    }
```

Hope this is more clear. Thanks